# Read data from Redshift and write it to S3 in partitions

Tags: aws-glue

I am trying to read tables (~200) (every 24 hours - The frequency could be as high as every hour) from Redshift and write it to S3 bucket. In my use case, each table has a different partition.

For example, *Transaction* table has this structure

```
TransactionID MerchantStore MerchantCity TransactionDate
```

Then my S3 folder for this will look like this:

```
Transaction
 - MerchantCity=NewYork
  - Year
   - Month
    - Date
 - MerchantCity=Seattle
  - Year
   - Month
    - Date
    ...
```

Which means the partition I am using for the Transaction table is
MerchantCity, YEAR(TransactionDate), Month(TransactionDate), Day(TransactionDate).

I tried reading the table from Redshift and then dumping it to S3 in partitions. here is the code for that:

```py
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

# Created this list just to emulate the behavior of partition schemes with only one table in Redshift.

partition_keys = ['txn_type','amount','trans_date','acceptor_ref','location_schema','settlement_date','merchant_city','merchant_state','merchant_country','mcc','industry_code','tran_code','reason_code','plan_id','pin_txn','eci','prescore_amount','batch_date','src_file_name','load_time']

txn_table_df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options (
    connection_type = 'redshift',
    connection_options = {"url": "jdbc:redshift://testredshiftcluster.**.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev", "user": "**", "password": "**","dbtable": "loyalty.dailyclienttxn", "redshiftTmpDir": "s3://loyalty-poc-arm/tempDirectory/"}
    )

def read_and_write(partition_key):
    path = "s3://loyalty-poc-arm/allpartitionsWithouParallelRun4/" + partition_key
    glueContext.write_dynamic_frame_from_options(
        frame = txn_table_df,
        connection_type = "s3",    
        connection_options = {"path": path, "partitionKeys": [partition_key]},
        format = "parquet")

#Used joblib to parallel execute the for loop so that I can write in  parallel
results = Parallel(n_jobs=-1, prefer="threads")(delayed(read_and_write)(partition_key) for partition_key in partition_keys)
```

After 3 hours of job execution, the job failed abruptly.

Is there anything I can do to speed up the process?
Here is my AWS Glue job configuration:

```
Worker type: G.2X
No of workers: 149
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

- Use the `UNLOAD` command to store the data from Amazon Redshift into Amazon S3
- Use Amazon Athena `CREATE TABLE AS` to convert the data into a new, partitioned table that is stored in Amazon S3

See: [Converting to Columnar Formats - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/convert-to-columnar.html)

That shows how to convert to partitioned Parquet format, but the method can be used for other formats too.

Comment: Hi @John, I think I forgot to mention in my post but this particular piece will run on a daily basis. Your suggestion is very good I this is a one-time activity. Sorry for the confusion. I have edited my post as well.